# Will currentUser() return an anonymous user Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I cannot seem to find this answer anywhere. When randomly authenticating a user with `base.auth().signInAnonymously()`, and then calling `currentUser()`, will it return that anonymous user?

Basically, I am trying to figure out if a user is actually logged in, or if they are anonymously authenticated. Please help.

Comment: Yes, it will. If you've having problems making this work, show the minimum code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen, are there any ways then to tell the difference between a real user and an anonymously authenticated user then?

Comment: @MichaelJones your code?

Comment: @FowotadeBabajide, I don't have any yet :) Just thinking about how I will have to code this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Yes, it will", like [Frank van Puffelen said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864380/will-currentuser-return-an-anonymous-user-firebase/40419290#comment67017031_39864380). You could get the user:

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
...
auth = Firebase.auth
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
```

and if the currentUser exists, you can find out if it is anonymous by using the `isAnonymous` field:

```
if (user?.isAnonymous) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: the user.isAnonymous() isn't documented clearly enough, thanks for this